# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform error

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

So, I'm trying to build a small application, which shows you the books you've added to the list. I tried to read data from my Firebase and display it on the main page, but I get the error which is in the title of this post.

(I can easily add information to database, though)

Here's my code:

```dart
body: StreamBuilder(

        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){

          if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('No data');
          return ListView.builder(

            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Container(
                key: Key(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id),

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 25, 0, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 160,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('url')),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('name'), style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontFamily: "Avenir",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),),

                              Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('author')),

                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.star, size: 24, color: Colors.orangeAccent,),
                                  Text(snapshot.data!.doc[index].get('rating')),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('category')),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: I get an error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'

Comment: change snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('url') to snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['url'] and same of all fields

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using `cloud_firestore 2.0.0`.

From the [migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration/):

> With the release of withConverter, numerous classes/functions take an
> extra generic parameter. In most cases, type inference should take
> care of the migration for you. But in some cases, you may have to
> specify that generic parameter yourself.

You need to include `Map<String, dynamic>` in your StreamBuilder. Like this:

```dart
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot){
      ...
  }
```

Comment: i still get the same error for some reason.

Comment: Okay, how about specifying the type when you want to get the field like this: `(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data as Map<String, dynamic>)['url']` ?

Comment: The argument type "Map<String, dynamic>" cannot be assigned to the parameter type "String"

Comment: Try this instead: `(snapshot.data!.docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['url']`

Comment: I get 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: What's your cloud firestore version?  2.0.0 ?

Comment: Yes, I have `cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0` in my `pubspec.yaml` file. You think I should try to change it to previous versions?

Comment: No, I want to try to reproduce the error so I can understand the fix